# VPN + Proxy Security

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, encryption

If I will be using VPN, and set a proxy in Firefox, will Firefox bypass VPN encryption and use only proxy?

I used Opera's built in "vpn" with Nord VPN desktop client and if I am correct, it somehow bypassed the vpn, leaving my traffic un-encrypted.

Comment: Please clarify which VPN software you are using, or how you are using it. If you are using a system-level VPN that encrypts all traffic, Firefox will connect to the proxy via the VPN. It will have no other way.

Comment: I am using a desktop client. Nord VPN.

Answer (score 0):

The VPN client will forward all traffic to the VPN server if the connection is OpenVPN, then using a proxy on the browser configuration would send requests to the proxy from the OpenVPN server.  Here is a small visualization:

No VPN, only proxy:
Home -> proxy -> web (web gets proxy IP address, proxy gets home IP address)
VPN, No proxy:

Home -> VPN -> web (web gets VPN server address, VPN gets home IP address)
VPN and proxy:
Home -> VPN -> proxy -> web (web gets proxy address, proxy gets VPN address, VPN gets home IP address)
So a VPN basically forwards your traffic. Using a proxy in the browser config will result in the VPN  contacting the proxy server rather than your home IP address.

Edit: Anything to the left of VPN in the visualization is encrypted, while everything to the right of VPN is unencrypted